# make a preloader class instead of having it in the document class

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, class, preloader, stage

I have built a basic preloader that runs in my document class. I'm having trouble with it. I'm guessing its due to what a class can and can not access from the stage?
theres 2 problems. the first is that I cant change the keyframe the stage is on from the class. the second is im getting an error 1009 if I comment that out.

```
package 
{


 import flash.display.MovieClip
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;

    public class Pre extends MovieClip
    {
        public function Pre()
        {
            loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,downloadFin);
            loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,preloadProgress);
            function preloadProgress(progressEvent:ProgressEvent):void
            {
                var floatLoaded:Number=loaderInfo.bytesLoaded/loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
                var newW:Number=this.width*floatLoaded;
                this.Fill.width=newW;
            }
            function downloadFin(event:Event):void
            {
                trace('fin')
                //stage.gotoAndStop(3);//frame with game
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried this.gotoAndStop(3);??

Comment: this would be the preloader not the stage.

Comment: this would be the document class"Pre" which should have inherited and should work

Comment: the code shown is a seperate class attached to a movieClip in the library. this.gotoAndStop would change frames in the Pre movieclip not the document. Ive done this is a snake game I made that had 4 or 5 different apple. each on a different frame.

Comment: ahhhhh you mentioned the document class and i thought it was refering to "Pre" in anycase to "Pre" needs to have already been added to the stage to have access to the stage. If that doesn't do it post your document class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to dispatch an event when the preloader is ready, making yor preloader more generic. Then add a listener in the document class like this:

```
private function setupPreloader() : void
{
    preloader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE , onPreloaderComplete);
preloader.start();
}

private function onPreloaderComplete(event : Event) : void
{
preloader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onPreloaderComplete);
preloader.dispose();

gotoAndStop(3);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way for me to have this in my preloader class instead of in the document class?